# Reference for a local density theorem for binary vectors

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, pr.probability

I have the following theorem written on my whiteboard, but have misplaced the reference. I believe the probabilistic method may be involved in the proof. Any pointers appreciated.

**Theorem** Let $v\in\{0,1\}^n$ be nonzero. Let $k=v_1+\ldots+v_n$ be its Hamming weight. Then there exists $i\leq j$ such that
$$v_i+v_{i+1}+\cdots+v_j\geq \frac{1}{14}\frac{k}{(1+\log_2(n/k))},$$ and
$$\min\{i-1,n-j\}\geq j-i,$$
for $n$ large enough. Note that this  implies
$$2i\geq j+1,\quad 2j\leq n-i$$ so that there is a locally dense interval not too near to the two ends of the vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the paper the result is from. It is Lemma 3.1 in

> "The unbounded error communication complexity of symmetric functions",
>   by A. A. Shertsov, Combinatorica 31 (5) (2011) 583–614.

Since there was an upvote for the question, I will give an outline of the proof below.

By symmetry,  we can assume that $v_1 + v_2 + ··· + v_m \geq  \frac{1}{2}k$ for some index $m \leq \lfloor n/2\rfloor$. Let $\alpha\in (0,1/2)$ be a parameter to be fixed later. Let $T\geq 0$
be the smallest  integer such that
$$v_1 +\cdots + v_{\lfloor m/2^T \rfloor}    < (1 − α)^T(v_1 + \cdots + v_m )\quad(1).$$
Clearly, $T\geq 1.$ Since $v_1 + \cdots +  v_{\lfloor m/2^T \rfloor}\leq m/2^T,$
we further  obtain
$$1\leq T\leq 1+ \frac{1+\log(n/k)}{\log(2-2\alpha)}.$$

The argument concludes by writing $$v_{1+\lfloor m/2^T \rfloor} + \cdots + v_{\lfloor m/2^{T-1} \rfloor}$$ as the difference 
$$ (v_1+\cdots+v_{\lfloor m/2^{T-1} \rfloor})-(v_1+\cdots+v_{\lfloor m/2^{T} \rfloor})\quad (2) ,$$ using the minimality of $T$ in (1) for lower bounding the first and upper bounding the second term on the RHS of (2), and applying a series of inequalities, giving
$$v_{1+\lfloor m/2^T \rfloor} + \cdots + v_{\lfloor m/2^{T-1} \rfloor}\geq \frac{1}{2} \alpha \left(1-\alpha\cdot \frac{1+\log(n/k)}{\log(2-2\alpha)}\right)k,$$
followed by judicious choices of $\alpha=0.23/(1+\log(n/k)),$ $i=\lfloor m/2^{T} \rfloor+1, $ and $j =\lfloor m/2^{T-1} \rfloor.$